# _objc_exception_throw / crash / stack trace

Tags: ios, objective-c, stack, stack-trace

I am trying to debug a crash log I got from Flurry Analytics but I can t see the problem. This is the stack trace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x181f36530 <redacted> + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x192f0c0e4 _objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x181e248e8 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 420
3   CoreFoundation                      0x181e3ff44 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:forKey:] + 60
4   memono                              0x10005f96c -[AppDelegate iCLoudSyncCheckNotificationSync:] + 1244
5   CoreFoundation                      0x181edcddc <redacted> + 20
6   CoreFoundation                      0x181e1b370 __CFXNotificationPost + 2060
7   Foundation                          0x182d3f520 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
8   memono                              0x10005c02c -[AppDelegate syncWithCompletion:] + 660
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x19355d994 <redacted> + 24
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x19355d954 <redacted> + 16
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x19356220c __dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
12  CoreFoundation                      0x181eee2ec <redacted> + 12
13  CoreFoundation                      0x181eec394 <redacted> + 1492
14  CoreFoundation                      0x181e191f4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
15  GraphicsServices                    0x18b23b6fc _GSEventRunModal + 168
16  UIKit                               0x1867aa10c _UIApplicationMain + 1488
17  memono                              0x100099b7c -[UpdatePromtRateViewController .cxx_destruct] + 220
18  libdyld.dylib                       0x19358aa08 <redacted> + 4
```

I also got some other crashes and it always starts with the [UpdatePromtRateViewController...] This is just a viewController I am showing once after an app update to promt the users to rate the app. There is a button that closes my app and leads directly to my app in the App Store app. Could it be that it is no "real crash" and I get this crash log only because the app is ended immediately by this button? 
Or has it to do with that dictionary? Maybe i put in nil objects? Could I solve this by doing something like - surround the dictionay with a "if object is not nil" statement?

I am not really good in stack trace reading and it would be great if someone could give me a hint what this crash log is trying to tell me !?

Thanks for help !

EDIT

There is no other message given by Flurry analytics... What I am doing is to set up all local notifications again to get that badge icon number sorted... it is working fine and the strange thing is that [UpdatePromtRateViewController] is always appearing in that crash log, and I use that only once, so there should be other crash logs without that -[UpdatePromtRateViewController] because I use that only once at first app start, then never again... Here is the code for what I am doing there

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionDelegate = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *requestData = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [requestData setEntity:entityDescriptionDelegate];
    NSError *error;


    NSArray *objectsArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestData error:&error];


    for (NSManagedObject *object in objectsArray) {



        if (!([object valueForKey:@"alarmDate"] == nil)) {


            _badge += 1;


            UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            alarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber  = _badge; // 1;
            alarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
            alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

            NSString *alarmTitleString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[object valueForKey:@"alarmTitle"]];

            alarm.alertBody = alarmTitleString;
            alarm.fireDate  = [object valueForKey:@"alarmDate"];
            alarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[object valueForKey:@"alarmID"] forKey:@"ID"];

            alarm.userInfo = userInfo;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];

            [object setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"alarmSet"];


            [UILocalNotification setBadge];

            alarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: What does the text of the exception say?

Comment: There should be an exception message that will give you a better idea of what's going on - I don't know Flurry Analytics, but they really should provide that to you.  It looks like you're making a dictionary with one item in it in your app delegate?  Check your data before going in, [NSNull null] instead of nil (or not populating at all).

Answer (score 2):

This method is crashing: `iCLoudSyncCheckNotificationSync:` and, as you surmise, it is most likely because you are passing `nil` for the key.

The crash trace implies a whole lot of heavy lifting during a C++ destructor.  That is bound to fail.   But the crash trace might be wrong;  a call from a destructor to UIApplicationMain() seems a bit odd.

In any case, yes, it is a real crash and even it is happening at app termination, you should probably figure out why and fix it.  In particular, if your application is terminating in response to a "quit" like button's press, it really shouldn't be triggering a cloud sync or other slow operation.